# Calculate total right and left turn

Tags: java

Lines made by four Line2D method with random x2,y2 position. **Every Line "end point" is "origin of" Next Line**.  Only first line x1,y1 position have fixed. I have already tried some coordinate based calculations, also tried using angle and degree based.

Comment: What is the success your code has, if it does not achieve what you want?

Comment: Is the code you show meant to be a program which can be run and demonstrate your success while also demonstrating your problem? If not, please make a [mcve]. Add a prose description of what it should do in contrast to what it does. Consider using examples.

Comment: How would it look like, if you successfully did "find out and calculate the total right and left turn"find out and calculate the total right and left turn"? How would that involve executing the shown code? What is missing?

Comment: dear,I foundin my code, which I wanted to get. I thanks to Mr. Bear, who helped me. And ofcourse, i did not typed all the code on page. But Mr. Bear udnerstood the problem, and also gave a solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

These boolean methods may help you solve your problem.
They assume that you start at point a, go to point b, and then turn to point c and that your y-axis is reversed (points down).

```
boolean isRightTurn(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
  return a.x * (b.y - c.y) + b.x * (c.y - a.y) +  c.x * (a.y - b.y) > 0;
}

boolean isLeftTurn(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
  return a.x * (b.y - c.y) + b.x * (c.y - a.y) +  c.x * (a.y - b.y) < 0;
}
```

To get the number of right, or left turns you would have to check at every turn, whether it is left, or right, and count them.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Bear. This method is working, and I found the number of right and left turns in code. So nice of you. Lord Krishna Bless You.